# Posting an unknown number of files to php

Tags: php, file-upload

I am currently working on php project where I need to upload files, but I have no way of knowing how many files the user will upload.

There will be one file upload by default on the form with a link to add another file upload. When the form is submitted how would I post all of the files to the php script if I don't know the number of files that are being uploaded.

Does it work in the same way as a checkbox array so you could have something like

```
<input type="file" name"myFile[]" />
<input type="file" name"myFile[]" />
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: [Similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post).

Comment: If you have an idea of how it might work, did you try it?

Comment: Give it a try, I dont see any reason why not ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, works fine.

try to do this, after post form with files:

```
<pre>
    <?php print_r($_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name']); ?>
</pre>
```

You will get a array. Access each file info with their index:

```
$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'][0];
$_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'][1];
```

Comment: Thanks I did try do that array thing that I mentioned in the question but it didn't work because I forgot to put set the form enctype.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works exactly like a checkbox array.