# Codeigniter- upload more than one file with only one input field

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible with codeigniter, or even at all, to have only one input field that allows a user to select multiple files to upload.  So basically you have

```
<input name="files" type="file">
```

rather than

```
<input name="file1" type="file">
<input name="file2" type="file">
<input name="file3" type="file">
```

I currently know how to implement the latter but think the former would be a cleaner model.

Comment: You could look at the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post . Note, it is quite a "new" feature, so older browsers might not support the multiple feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you even looked into [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)?

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Send these files:<br />
  <input name="userfile[]" type="file" multiple=""/><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Send files" />
</form>
```

you access it in PHP as $_FILES

Comment: While I appreciate your answer. According to the documentation I would still need multiple inputs which isn't really a solution to my problem.

Comment: Sorry I forgot one little thing :)  multiple="" try it now

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` has to be like this (so, you can select multiple files at once)

```
<input multiple type="file" name="files[]" />
```

Notice `multiple` attribute but not supported by all/old browsers.

[An Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/7jvKB/1/) and also take look at [this tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/multiple-file-upload).

Comment: just remember [quoted from W3Shools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp) 'The multiple attribute is supported in Internet Explorer 10, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari'...if you want <IE10 than flash would be used

Comment: @gwillie, I think you didn't read my answer properly, I've already mentioned it.

Comment: uhm i scanned but certainly didnt take it in, obviously...my apologises