# Form having more than one file input not submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

Actually I having one form will four File Input text box (Like Below).

[image]

While Submitting form means it is not sending data to server. When i seeing in console that status still in **pending**(See Below).[image]

Don't why it is happening. Please Kindly help me to over come from this.

This Is my Code:

```
<form action="file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Upload 1 <input type="file" name="file1"><br>       
    Upload 2 <input type="file" name="file2">   <br>    
    Upload 3 <input type="file" name="file3">       <br>
    Upload 4 <input type="file" name="file4">       <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Thanks,

Comment: Check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

Comment: Show your code what you tried till now.

Comment: <html>
 <form action="file.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  Upload 1 <input type="file" name="file1"><br>  
  Upload 2 <input type="file" name="file2"> <br> 
  Upload 3 <input type="file" name="file3">  <br>
  Upload 4 <input type="file" name="file4">  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
</html>

Comment: Actually it is working in my local, Not working while go to server. Kindly answer some what urgent.

Comment: @GaneshSalunkhe : Thanks, I have try that solution also but same problem occurs. Upload 1 <input type="file" name="file1[]" multiple=true>

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37614576/html-form-having-more-than-one-file-input-not-submitting