# File Input Field - Name Variable Array

Tags: php, file, variables

So this may be easy but I can't figure it out.  I have a file field and the name is set dynamically with a variable.  I need this name to be an array using $Var[] so that the user can select multiple files.  When I try the following I keep getting errors:

```
"<input id='$Var' name='$Var[]' type='file' multiple/>"
"<input id='$Var' name='$Var".[]."' type='file' multiple/>"
"<input id='$Var' name='".$Var."[]' type='file' multiple/>"
```

I have tried all three of the above and keep getting errors.  When I remove the variable and just type in the field name it works fine.

```
"<input id='File' name='File[]' type='file' multiple/>"
```

Not sure if need to escape something or what.  Please help and thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select and upload multiple files with HTML and PHP, using HTTP POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

Comment: @AvinashR in what world are these two questions duplicates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use curly braces around your variable name:

```
"<input id='$Var' name='{$Var}[]' type='file' multiple/>"
```

Comment: It's always nice to know why you have to do something.

Comment: yeah, I agree. And even better to get to know it by oneself from credible source :)

Answer (score 0):

Use your variable this way;

```
    <?php
    $fieldName = "FileInput";
    echo "<input id='{$fieldName}' name='{$fieldName}[]' type='file' multiple/>";
```

And reading this answer may be helpful;
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2596838/3399234