# how to add muliple file upload using jQuery to exsisting function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have below upload function that uploads one image at a time, how do I adapt it to handle multiple files ?

```
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}
function uploadFile(){
    var checked_box = $('input:checkbox:checked').val();
    var file = _("image").files[0];
    var imageFile =$("#image").val();
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append( 'action','add_photo');
    formdata.append("image", file);
    jQuery.each($("input[name^='image']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formdata.append('photo['+i+']', file);
    }); 
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "includes/add_photo.inc.php?checked_box="+checked_box);
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
```

**Associated file input html**

```
<input name="image[]" id="image" type="file" multiple style="display:none" value=""/>
```

Comment: `jQuery.each($("input[name^='image']")[0].files` not appending `file` to `formdata` ?

Comment: @ guest271314 the jquery.each was something I tried? In console i can see by the file size being uploaded that there are multiple images, however there is only one image file shown in the param console, so I think I need to figure out how to get all of the file names somehow

Comment: See  http://stackoverflow.com/q/1175347/2801559 , http://stackoverflow.com/q/28856729/2801559