# Error uploading multiple images at the same time

Tags: php

I am trying to upload multiple photos at the same time but there seems to be an error with my script. If for example, I select 10 different photos, one particular image  is uploaded 10 times (ignoring the other 9 images). This is the script:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["_photo"]["name"]); $i++) {  
    if (!empty($_FILES['_photo']['name'][$i])) {

    if (($_FILES['_photo']['type'][$i] == 'image/jpeg') OR ($_FILES['_photo']['type'][$i] == 'image/png') OR ($_FILES['_photo']['type'][$i] =='image/gif')) {
        $upload_folder = "./profile_pix/";
        $pic_name = time() . ".jpg";
        $pic_path = $upload_folder . $pic_name;

        require_once "include/resize.php";
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['_photo']['tmp_name'][$i], $pic_path)) {
            $image = new Resize($pic_path);
            $image->resizeImage(180, 180, 'crop');
            $image->saveImage($pic_path);

        }
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO photos
            (photo, member_id, photo_id)
             VALUES
            ('$pic_name', :session_id, :offer_count)";
            $db -> query($sql2, array('session_id' => $_SESSION['id'], 'offer_count' => $offer_count));
    }else {
            header ("Location: submitoffer.php?err=03");
        }


    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="_photo"  name="_photo[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML?

Comment: Can you post what error you get????

Comment: You talking about the values in the database or the image uploads or both?

Comment: Post the array structure of `$_FILES["_photo"]`

Comment: @Raphioly-San html added

Comment: Handling a file upload with multiple photo's at the same time can be a hassle... I prefer one image per element... I wonder why you're using `multiple` combined with a `name=""` which results in an array as well... But that's all the info I can give at this time...

Comment: @Uchiha Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ) [type] => Array ( [0] => ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 4 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 0 ) )

Comment: @radioactive Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File upload is working fine.

The line

```
$pic_name = time() . ".jpg";
```

is always evaluating to same value.

As logically all files are getting uploaded on same `time()`.

Instead use:

```
$pic_name = $i . '_'. time() . ".jpg";
```

To add uniqueness.

Comment: I could argue using `uniqid()` as replacement for time(), but that still doesn't say why the same photo is uploaded 10 times ;)

Comment: Probably it uploads all files with the same name since time returns unix timestamp which is in seconds and php can easily upload 10 or more files in under a second

Answer (score 0):

try this, and you will see what is happening:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

And in your HTML, make sure you use different names, like this:

```
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
<input name="userfile[]" type="file" />
```

Then pick them up by each name. Just inspect the content of $_FILES to understand the structure.

I also advice you serious do some error checking.

Comment: It should have an array as name in HTML

Comment: I changed it to an array, but that isn't necessary. You can also name them differently. I prefer your suggestion above giving them different names, so there you go!

Answer (score 0):

100% working and tested code:

**upload.php:**

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
  if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
      $file_name  = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
      $file_size  = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
      $file_tmp   = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
      $file_type  = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
      if($file_type == "image/jpg" || $file_type == "image/png" || $file_type == "image/jpeg" || $file_type == "image/gif" ) {      
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);        
      }   
    }
    header('location:uploads.html'); 
  }
}
else { header('location:404.html'); }
?>
```

**upload.html**

```
<form id="upload_images" action="upload.php" method="POST"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="files[]" id="file" multiple="true" />                
      <input type="submit" id="btn_upload"  value="U P L O A D" />
</form>
```