# Upload Multiple file

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload

Source Code :

```
<form role="form" action="uploadrit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="input" >Choose File Of CSV Format</label>
        <input class="input" type="file" name="file" id="file" class="form-control" required="required">        
        <button class="input" type="submit" name="AddFile" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to select all file from directory using file upload control  and send one by one file to uploadrit.php.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Submit your code and someone will help you, just show your effort. :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select and upload multiple files with HTML and PHP, using HTTP POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

Comment: make question more clear based on code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add **multiple** attribute to your file tag:

```
<form role="form" action="uploadrit.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label class="input" >Choose File Of CSV Format</label>
        <input class="input" type="file" name="file" multiple id="file" class="form-control" required="required">        
        <button class="input" type="submit" name="AddFile" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If you need to handle the files via Javascript, you can use File API. Example documentation: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Answer (score 0):

Instead sending the files one by one, use the `multiple` flag and send the files as an array. Here is an example:

`<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>`

Pay attention to `input` where I've used the `multiple` flag as well as have declared the `name` of the input as an array. In your PHP file, loop through `$_FILES['files']` to get all selected files.