# Form post only 1 file

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using "Bootstrap File Input" in order to upload files (http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input)

If I browse and choose 2 files then, when I post I get 2 files. But if I choose 1 file and then browse again and choose another file, then in the preview area I see 2 files, but when I post I get only 1.

Is it possible to fix it?

scripts:

```
<link href="bootstrap-file_input/css/fileinput.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/bootstrap-file_input/js/fileinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
$("#files").fileinput({
    theme: 'fa',
    uploadUrl: '#', // you must set a valid URL here else you will get an error
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'bmp', 'zip', 'rar', 'csv', 'doc', 'docx', 'txt', 'pdf', 'xml', 'xls', 'xlsx'],
    overwriteInitial: true,
    showUpload: false,
    showUploadedThumbs: false,
//  allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg", "bmp"],
    maxFileSize: 3000,
    maxFilesNum: 10,
    dropZoneEnabled: false
}); 
</script>
```

html:

```
<input id="files" name='file[]' type="file" multiple class="file" data-overwrite-initial="false" data-min-file-count="2">
```

Comment: Show your PHP code !

Comment: ` if ($_POST)
 {
  var_dump ($_FILES);
}`

@Goms

Comment: And result ? what return `var_dump($_FILES['file'])` ?

Comment: Bro Check this one -

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post