# how to upload multiple images on a website using php

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms, image

I am trying to upload multiple images on my website when user clicks on upload button. I was able to do that for one image, but I am not sure how to do for multiple images.

My code:

index.php

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="backend.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file" >
      <button type="submit" name="submit">button</button>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

database.php

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');
    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 10000000) {
                  $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).".".$fileActualExt;
                  $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                  move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                  header("Location: index.php?uploadsuccess");
            } else {
                echo "Your file is too big!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "There was an error uploading your file";
        }
       
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
    }
}

?>
```

I changed a bit in my code (index.html) so I can at least select multiple images:   `<input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>`
but when I do that and click on upload it says:

Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testing/backend.php on line 11

Warning: end() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/testing/backend.php on line 12
You cannot upload files of this type!

I assume cause it expects it to be string but I have an array now. How can I make my code work in database.php for multiple files? It works for single image, but not for multiple. If someone can reckon something?

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select and upload multiple files with HTML and PHP, using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

Comment: @nielsdg Yes, it does. But, how can I upload those images to mysqli database?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's say you have this HTML:

```html
<form action="backend.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple />
    <button type="submit" name="submit">button</button>
</form>
```

Normally (without `multiple` and with `name="file"`), your PHP would receive something like this:

```php
$_FILES['file']['name'] // contains the file name
```

However, sending multiple files, your PHP will receive these files as following:

```php
$_FILES['file']['name'][0] // contains the first file name
$_FILES['file']['name'][1] // contains the second file name
// ...
```

[Read more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php).