# Uploading multipile files using HTML file input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i'm trying to upload a bunch of files using file type input with php i tried so far to make upload only one file and it worked the problem is that when i added `[]` to the name attribute it started to print `Uploaded data error`.

HTML

```
<form id="theform" action="upload.php" onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); return myFunction2();" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="file" name="uploadedFile[]" onchange="uptoserver();" style="display:none;"type="file" multiple>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div id="buttons" style="display:none !important;">
            <button type="submit"  class="btn wbtn" style="font-family:Hana; font-size:18px; border:1px solid black !important;">
                <img src="style\image\add.png" width="32" />&nbsp;تكوين كشف&nbsp;
            </button>&nbsp;
            <button type="button" class="btn wbtn" style="font-family:Hana; font-size:18px; border:1px solid black !important;">
                <img src="style\image\camera.png" width="32" />&nbsp;إضافة نموذج&nbsp;
            </button>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javacript :

```
function myFunction2(){
    document.getElementById('file').click();
    console.log('reading form');
}

function uptoserver(){
    // var formscounter = parseInt(document.getElementById("counter").value);
    if(!document.getElementById("file").files.length == 0) {
        const form = document.getElementById('theform');
        form.submit();
        console.log('fucking working');
    }
}
```

upload.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    echo "Empty data, please select file";
    die;
}

if (!isset($_FILES["uploadedFile"])) {
    echo "Wrong data struct";
    die;
}

if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]['error'] != 0) {
    echo "Uploaded data error";
    die;
}
$target_dir    = "uploads/";
$target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]);
$allowUpload   = true;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$maxfilesize   = 80000000;
$allowtypes    = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        //
    } else {
        echo "This's not image file.";
        $allowUpload = false;
    }
}

if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    require "other\\fileExsist.php";
    $allowUpload = false;
}
if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["size"] > $maxfilesize) {
    require "other\\fileSize.php";
    $allowUpload = false;
}

if (!in_array($imageFileType,$allowtypes )) {
    require "other\\fileExtenstion.php";
    $allowUpload = false;
}

if ($allowUpload) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        //   echo "File ". basename( $_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]). " uploaded success.";
        //   echo $target_file;
        require "prepare.php";
        echo count($_FILES["uploadedFile"]);
    } else {
        echo "Error when upload file.";
    }
    // $total = count($_FILES['uploadedFile']['name']);

// // Loop through each file
// for( $i=0 ; $i < $total ; $i++ ) {

//   //Get the temp file path
//   $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'][$i];

//   //Make sure we have a file path
//   if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
//     //Setup our new file path
//     $newFilePath = "uploads/" . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'][$i];

//     //Upload the file into the temp dir
//     if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

//       //Handle other code here

//     }
//   }
// }
} else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I select and upload multiple files with HTML and PHP, using HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175347/how-can-i-select-and-upload-multiple-files-with-html-and-php-using-http-post)

Comment: You'd need to also modify the php so it loops through the list of uploaded files. You can't expect code which is only able to cope with one file to suddenly cope with several...it needs restructuring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original structure works perfectly fine because, when you're uploading a single file, **line 18** is `if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]['error'] != 0)`, and this returns 0.

When you send through an array of files, even if a single file is sent, the `uploadFile` array is now an array of arrays, as below.

```
[_FILES] => Array
    (
        [uploadedFile] => Array
            (
                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => funnyMusclePose.jpg
                    )

                [type] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => image/jpeg
                    )

                [tmp_name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => C:\Development\wamp64\tmp\phpE949.tmp
                    )

                [error] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0
                    )

                [size] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 735092
                    )

            )

    )
```

This means `$_FILES["uploadedFile"]['error']` will always evaluate to true because it doesn't equal 0.

From here on out, you can wrap this entire function in a `for()` loop and iterate over each of the internal array items to get the data you're after, ie.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"]); $i++) {
  if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]['error'][$i] != 0)
  {
    echo "Uploaded data error";
    die;
  }
  $target_dir    = "uploads/";
  $target_file   = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["name"][$i]);
  $allowUpload   = true;
  $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
  $maxfilesize   = 80000000;
  $allowtypes    = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');

  if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["tmp_name"][$i]);
      if($check !== false)
      {
          //
      }
      else
      {
          echo "This's not image file.";
          $allowUpload = false;
      }
  }

  if (file_exists($target_file))
  {
      require "other\\fileExsist.php";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }
  if ($_FILES["uploadedFile"]["size"][$i] > $maxfilesize)
  {
      require "other\\fileSize.php";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }

  if (!in_array($imageFileType,$allowtypes ))
  {
      require "other\\fileExtenstion.php";
      $allowUpload = false;
  }
  
  // Add the rest of the code here
}
```